# The getter 'length' was called on null in GridView.count()

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I was implementing the GridView.count within a Consumer() and got this error: `The getter 'length' was called on null.`

But when I tried to print the list length, it is not null.

```
I/flutter ( 6581): 7

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification>:
The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length
```

Here is my code:

```
        print(pr.productList.length);
        return GridView.count(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          childAspectRatio: 1/2,
          children: List.generate(
            pr.productList.length, 
            (int index) => ProductCard(product:pr.productList[index])
          ),
        );
```

How can I resolve this issue? Even after the length is not null.

> NOTE: The issue was caused by another API call, which was returning null and not handled correctly.

Comment: strange. Can you share other relevant part of the code?

Comment: Hello @Himanshu Sharma, I can see that your GridView.count doesn't have "itemCount" property. Please set "itemCount: pr.productList.length" in your GridView.count.

Comment: Hey, The issue was from another API call, which was returning null. Sorry for the late response.